# How to let a role to change field formatter under view mode?

Tags: entities

I don't mean to change view modes, I mean to change fields' formatters arbitrarily by some roles under the same view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit unclear.

But for what I understood, try in this page:

> yourwebsite/admin/config/content/formats

To edit permissions of roles, go here:

> yourwebsite/admin/people/permissions

Comment: I mean formatters, not text format. Defaulty, only administrator can change field formatters on the "Manage Display" page. I'd like to allow some roles to change it on the entity view page.